# how to clean register_shutdown_function

Tags: php

in test.php

```
function close() {
echo "end";
}
register_shutdown_function("close");
exit();
```

when i call method "exit()" to end.I expect to see nothing.
how to clean register functions or skip this.

Comment: Then... don't output anything from your shutdown handler...?

Comment: Seems like someone made an issue out of this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53702

Comment: @deceze yes.And register_shutdown_functions("close") must be called in head.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {});
```

Comment: While technically a correct answer to the question, I laughed so hard I woke everyone up. Upvote.

Comment: It's a bad solution to a bad problem, a perfect match! :)

Comment: @nyson `register_shutdown_function("close");`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Every time you call register_shutdown_function it just *adds* a function to call at shutdown time *after* the ones you've already added.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the documentation for `\register_shutdown_function` says it will call the function upon `exit()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

What are you using shutdown functions for that you don't want an exit() call to trigger?